# I have a constructor but I need to return the output to main.cpp. I cannot use getstring function!! any ideas how to accomplish this??

Tags: c++, string

```
               CXMLString::CXMLString (string content, string tag)
               {
                    ostringstream convert;
                string result;
                result << "<" << tag << ">" << content << "</" << tag << ">";
                cout << result;
               }
```

This is the task where I am stuck!!!

Create a multiline element by concatunating the previously created elements.

```
string structure = "\n\t" + myXMLString1 + "\n\t" + myXMLString2+"\n";
CXMLString myXMLString3(structure,"structure");
```

Konnen sie helfen bitte!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to do this in c++ even though it is not specified.

If it is C++, you may add another argument to the constructor [assuming you are free to modify CXMLString class]

`CXMLString::CXMLString (string content, string tag, string& Result)`

Then you can assign the combined string to the Result and get the value of it ehere you create the CXMLString object.

Comment: But I am not allowed to modify the CXMLString class. :(

Comment: @Harsha : You may inherit it, if it is feasible.

Comment: I got it working this wayCXMLString::CXMLString (string content, string tag)
{
 ostringstream convert;
 ostringstream result;
 result << "<" << tag << ">" << content << "</" << tag << ">";
 this -> assign(result.str());
}

Comment: @ Harsha : Happy that you sorted it out. At stack overflow there is option answer your own question, so that others can use the information. Btw I am not aware of the assign function and internals of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is supposed to be a constructor, you instantiate new CXMLString members with call like this:

CXMLString myCxml(content, tag);

Without knowing the class details, we cannot answer. But usually you populate some member (private?) data member with the passed in arguments. By "return output to main.cpp" are you referring this kind of use case below?

```
    int main(){
     CXMLString myCxml("MYContent", "content");

     cout << myCxml;
```

If this is what you are looking, you need to overload the operator << for this class. Which will print the internal data member populated from the constructors into wherever stream the output is fed into.

Comment: But I assume in the assign function you are populating the member variable of the class. Look at the code what assign does, and do the same assignment inside this constructor. That way you save a function call overhead of calling assign() inside this current constructor you are writing.